# Como creo eventos en un widget?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Tengo la intención de crear un widget que consistiría en un simple botón que al ser pulsado ejecuta una acción.

He estado viendo tutoriales como este "[Widgets SGOliver](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/interfaz-de-usuario-en-android-widgets-ii/)", entiendo gran parte de lo que explican ahí pero mi problema viene en la parte de los Intent y PendingIntent a la hora de añadir acción a un botón.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("net.sgoliver.android.widgets.ACTUALIZAR_WIDGET");
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

controles.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BtnActualizar, pendingIntent);
```

Ese código hace que un botón en el widget actualice la información en al widget para no tener que esperar por la actualización automatica de éste.

No entiendo concretamente en qué parte del código se le dice al botón que actualice la información.

Entiendo que se crea un intent con el nombre de la acción y se le pasa por parámetro en el método `getBroadcasT()`, pero no entiendo cómo es que el botón entiende que debe actualizar la información (por decirlo de alguna manera).

Sé que me explico fatal pero sería una gran ayuda si me pudieran orientar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al ponerle un id a tu botón y usar la función `.setOnClickPendingIntent`, le estás haciendo referencia en la siguiente sentencia:

```
controles.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.BtnActualizar, pendingIntent);
```

Cuando usas `R.id.BtnActualizar` en realidad estás haciendo referencia a tu botón con id `BtnActualizar` dentro del proyecto. Al ser las id's únicas e irrepetibles, sabes seguro que le estás haciendo referencia a tu botón.

Es decir, en realidad lo que tu código está haciendo es esperar hasta que el botón sea pulsado y lance el Intent, evento que detectas mediante el `setOnClickPendingIntent`. Una vez el botón ha sido pulsado, el `Intent` es lanzado.

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deseas realizar es un [Widget](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html?hl=zh-cn)  que ejecute una acción al pulsar un boton, simplemente crea un layout personalizado para tu [Widget](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html?hl=zh-cn) en el cual agregarías un boton:

widget_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <StackView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/stack_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:loopViews="true"
        tools:ignore="NewApi" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

para obtener en tu Widget el boton:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ejecutar alguna acción en el [Widget](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html?hl=zh-cn), se realiza mediante un tipo especial de Intent, el **[PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

Obviamente para que funcione tienes que [configurar](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html?hl=zh-cn) el receiver en el archivo `Manifest.xml`, el `appwidget-provider` , etc...

Como ejemplo este [proyecto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/b01438e7f0fed8f795ddec4be43066905f03d0cc/AppWidget) de un buen conocido, Mark Murphy ( @CommonsWare )

Comment: ¿Alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo? **En verdad quien vota sabe de lo que estoy hablando?**, el código y la imagen es de un proyecto personal.