# ¿Como Crear Un Widget Desde Codigo Java?

Tags: android, android-widget

Me he preguntado y estaba trabajando en otra prueba con los widgets y me pregunte se yo puedo crear un widget desde código. Una idea de lo que digo:crear un app que al colocar texto en un EditTex y seleccionar una imagen se cree un nuevo widget con esas propiedades. Si sabe si se puede lograr me seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Aquì hay un tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uNI3T3DwTw

Comment: otro tutorial : http://computerhoy.com/paso-a-paso/moviles/crea-tu-propio-widget-personalizado-tu-movil-android-26057

Comment: Mírate esta otra pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28854/como-creo-eventos-en-un-widget/28855

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como creo eventos en un widget?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28854/como-creo-eventos-en-un-widget)