# ¿Cómo crear un widget con un imagebutton?

Tags: android

¿Cómo puedo crear un widget?

Es que creo el widget provider que me brinda Android Studio pero no entiendo mucho.

Comment: no tienes nada de código o algún avance para poder ayudarte mejor ...

Comment: Por favor publica el código con lo que hayas intentado, por más que no esté funcionando

Answer (score 1):

> Cómo crear un widget con un imagebutton?

Simplemente agrega a tu Layout (FrameLayout) el botón, un ejemplo usando un `StackView`, por ejemplo:

widget_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <StackView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/stack_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:loopViews="true"
        tools:ignore="NewApi" />

    <ImageButton
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myImagebutton" />

</FrameLayout>
```

obtendrías algo similar a esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para saber como crear el Widget, te recomiendo esta [**respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28862/95).

Comment: muchas gracias!! probare inmediatamente!! :D